# How do I create a method that stores names in Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am trying to create a method that stores names of and then   (possibly in another method) append them to each other to make an array. Interests me is the size of the array.

To explain better let's say I have three people in a group and then I want to have a group with a fixed number of people. for instance, I need to define "addPerson" and "people group" in the code below:

```
| People |
People := People new.
People 
    addPerson: Person John;
    addPerson: Person Adam;
    addPerson: Person Josh.
self assert: People peopleGroup size = 3
```

I'm very new to Smalltalk and Pharo so this might be a very beginner question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first point out a mistake in your code so we can then focus on your question.

Given that you are sending the message `new` to `People`, we can assume that you already have created the class `People`. There is a problem, however, in the two first lines

```
| People |
People := People new.
```

which should have been written like

```
| people |
people := People new.
```

or

```
| group |
group := People new.
```

otherwise, you would be assigning an instance of `People` to the class `People` itself, which would have rendered the class impossible to be reached by name. Of course, the Smalltalk compiler would prevent you from having an uppercase temporary, let alone one that collides with a class name. Still, it should be clear to you that you don't want to change the binding between the identifier `People` and the class it represents.

The cascade that follows, looks partially ok, provided your class `People` implements the method `addPerson:`.

The last expression could be simplified to

```
 self assert: people size = 3,
```

which will only require you to implement the `size` method in `People` so that it answers with the number of "persons" it holds.

Other suspicious messages are `Person john`, etc. You should add a class side method `newNamed:` in `Person` and write instead:

```
Person newNamed: 'John'
```

where

```
newNamed: aString
  ^self new name: aString
```

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed the first line for the class.

people is a class, and each of the names like Adam, John are are objects.

the point is having the names of the people in an Array or Collection to be able to refer to later or have the number of them (using size peopleGroup).

Comment: For storing the people add an instance variable to the `People` class, say, `contents`; initialize it as an `OrderedCollection new`, and implement `addPerson: aPerson` as `contents add: aPerson`. Finally, implement `size` as `^contents size`.

Comment: can you explain a bit more? as I said I'm very beginner.

Comment: Sure. Just tell me where you got lost.

Comment: So what I have to do is to define methods in order to make the code work. In the code above, the methods "addPerson" and "peoplGroup" are to be implemented. While "people" exists as a class. 

I have to implemented the code as you said like `addPerson: aCar
people add:aPerson.
^contents size`

but I'm not sure what i've done wrong as it still doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Append your code to the question (without deleting the original one), tell us the error message you get, and we will know how to help you.